# Python3: Deleting enemy from dynamic array when colliding with the player

Tags: python, object, pygame

I am creating a sidescroller shooter game in which the enemies(drones)spawn contantly on the right side of the screen. The recently created enemies are appended to a list `drones` Each enemy goes towards the left of the screen. Once they are out of the screen, they get removed from the list.

I also want to remove the drones when they collide with the player. The following code works properly as long as there are multiple objects in the `drones` list, but when the list has only one item (so one drone is on the screen) that drone does not get deleted upon collision.

I have no idea why the first list item cannot be destroyed.

```
drones = []
class Drone
    #other call methods

    def hit(self):
        del drones[drones.index(self)]

def generate_enemy():
    global drones
    if len(drones) < 20:    
        if (random.randint(1,100) == 1):
            drones.append(Drone(screenWidth, random.randint(300,500)) 

def main():
    global drones
    while True:
       #main loop stuff happening
       if condition == True:
           generate_enemy():
       #main loop stuff happening
       if player and (len(drones) > 0):
           for i in range(len(drones)-1):
               if drones[i].hitbox.colliderect(player.hitbox):
                   drones[i].hit()
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" way to do this in pygame is to let your classes inherit from [`Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite), then use a [`Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) instead of a simple list to store your enemies, and using [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) for collision detection with the `dokill` argument set to `True`.